# AJAX - JSON Date undefined

Tags: json, ajax

I get my JSON from my Own PHP file. I read the Json with Ajax and all is fine. But when I want to display the Date it shows me undefined.

My JSON TAG: `"pubDate": "17.06.2015 15:59"`

And my Ajax output: `result[i].published`

I tried something with `moment.js` but somehow I don't got the result I want.

How can I parse Json String to a Date in Ajax? Or is it in JSON a Data and I need the String and convert it in Ajax to data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you json string is like "pubDate": "17.06.2015 15:59" tha you code needs to be like `result[i].pubDate` because "published" is not exists in you json string.

for parsing date string to javascript date object you can try this library : http://www.datejs.com/ and this is sample code : http://www.datejs.com/2007/11/27/getting-started-with-datejs/

Comment: oh, sure you are right :D do i need to convert it in a date format? because i need to filter by date. And how i convert into date?

Comment: @Solu - for date format, you need to parse string in javascript and by that you can create date object in javascript --- but if your formate is working fine than you dont need to do any thing

Comment: @Solu - you can use this libarary http://www.datejs.com/ , for parsing date , check updated answer

Comment: OK Thanks for that hint. i did it with Date.parse and it works but not correctly. i have 2 input boxes with dates. 1st date is the start date and the 2nd date is the end date. iI parsed both Inputs and i also parsed result[i].pubDate, but i dont get all entries which are in the time period i selected ----- My Entries are form 04.12.2014 until 19.02.2015 and when i select startdate 03.12.2014 and enddate TODA, i have to get all entries, but i only get 2

Comment: @Solu - have you included library file in you code as suggested ..http://www.datejs.com/2007/11/27/getting-started-with-datejs/ as suggest here

Comment: no i did not, but now i did, and i get the same result...only 2 entries

Comment: @Solu - you have to try this var d1 = Date.parse('07.15.2007');

Comment: i did, like this : if( Date.parse(result[i].pubDate) > parsedDatum1 && Date.parse(result[i].pubDate) < parsedDatum2)

Comment: @Solu - first check this Date.parse(result[i].pubDate) giving you output or not

Comment: @Solu - and for comparison ob date you follow this answer of SO : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript

Comment: @Solu - if its not working than you can wite logic of parsing string and create date object from that ...hint is you have to break string first by . and than by : and take value of splitted value and build date object

Comment: @Solu- is that worked for you .....I can provide code for prasing date but better you do that simple work of parsing by yourself , that way you will learn ...do upvote or accept answer if it worked for you